# Turbine with Db4objects.Db4o.Linq.dll gives Unable to load one or more of the requested types exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container, db4o, turbine

In my asp.net-mvc application I'm trying to set up Turbine.
The initialization code goes as follows:

```
public class MvcApplication : TurbineApplication
{
    static MvcApplication()
    {
        ServiceLocatorManager.SetLocatorProvider(() => new UnityServiceLocator());           
    }
}
```

and I have then a set of registrars comparable to the following one:

```
public class UserRepositoryRegistration : IServiceRegistration
{
    public void Register(IServiceLocator locator)
    {
        locator.Register<IUserRepository, Db4oUserRepository>();
    }
}
```

If I try to run, I get the following error somewhere after the SetLocatorProvider, but before entering any of the register methods:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
>
> Source Error: 
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> ```
>     [ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.]
>        System.Reflection.Module._GetTypesInternal(StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +0
>        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() +105
>        MvcTurbine.ComponentModel.DefaultAutoRegistrator.AutoRegister(ServiceRegistration serviceRegistration) +338
>        MvcTurbine.Web.RotorContext.ProcessAutomaticRegistration(AutoRegistrationList registrationList) +155
>        MvcTurbine.Web.RotorContext.AutoRegistrationForContext() +163
>        MvcTurbine.Web.RotorContext.Turn() +37
>        MvcTurbine.Web.TurbineApplication.ExecuteContext() +43
>        MvcTurbine.Web.TurbineApplication.TurnRotor() +65
>        MvcTurbine.Web.TurbineApplication.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) +85
> ```

**UPDATE**
Narrowed down the problem library to Db4objects.Db4o.Linq.dll
As soon as I have this library as a references (not even "using", just added to references) in one of my libraries that is referenced in my mvc webapplication I get the above mentioned YSOD. All other Db4o libraries work just fine.

**METTRE À JOUR**
Tried swapping the UnityServiceLocator with the WindsosServiceLocator and the NinjectServiceLocator. Exact same results, so more then likely the problem doesn't originate in either of the libs.

**OPPDATERING**
To recreate the error page it suffices to take the following steps:

- Create new Mvc application (doesn't matter wat version)
- Alter gloabal.asax.cs code to use MvcTurbine and add needed MvcTurbine libs
   You will find everything still works as expected
- Add Db4objects.Db4o.dll
   Still everything works
- Add Db4objects.Db4o.linq.dll
   YSOD

Any ideas on where and how to debug this?

Comment: What's the content of the LoaderExceptions property?

Comment: I'm trying to find out, but don't have a clue where the exception is originating. VS doesn't break on the exception but just shows me the output in my browser. I tried finding the LoaderException in the Exceptions dialog of VS, but to no avail

Comment: On second reading of your request: I don't know where this property is at either. Starting to sound rather clueless ey :S

Comment: Found the exception type in VS and set it to break on throw, nothing happened.

Comment: Darn, could this be a Mvc1 vs MVC2 thing?
I totally forgot I was running an MVC2 site.

Comment: @boris: are you sure that you have all the assemblies that Db4objects.Db4o.Linq.dll references along with it?

Comment: @Jb Evain: thx for your attention. The library on itself builds and does it's job in other situations. I'm referencing the Db4objects.Db4o.dll and Db4objects.Db4o.linq.dll. Is there something I'm missing? I updated the OP with the most bare instructions to recreate the behavior.

Comment: Look at Db4objects.Db4o.Linq's references in reflector or in ildasm. You'll need Mono.Cecil and Cecil.FlowAnalysis as well.

Comment: Well, ok. I'll try that out tomorow. Howcome I never needed them  before and now I do?

Comment: @boris: they are referenced by Db4objects.Db4o.Linq, and are used by it. So you do need them around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of writing down a proper answer. I think you're getting a TypeLoadException triggered by a failure to load an assembly that is referenced by Db4objects.Db4o.Linq.

Looking at it in ildasm shows that it requires the following assemblies that are shipped with db4o (use the same assemblies that came with Db4objects.Db4o.Linq to avoid any mismatch).

Those assemblies are:

- Mono.Cecil
- Cecil.FlowAnalysis

For the record, abd as of today, they're used by the LINQ to db4o query optimizer to analyze properties access in linq queries.

Comment: Note that in future releases, the usage of Mono.Cecil and Cecil.FlowAnalysis have been replaced by a Mono.Reflection assembly.

Answer (score 2):

In order for Turbine to register your types, it needs to have the hosting assembly (Db4objects.Db4o.Linq) and ANY other assemblies that the hosting assembly might reference.

The stack trace in your original post says that when trying to resolve the types for your application something failed to resolve, which in this case it's not present.

Comment: Jeps, as @Jb Evain showed, it were a few libraries that db4o uses that weren't referenced correctly in my project. Now on to getting Nhaml my default view engine

Comment: Adding view engines was a matter of adding the correct reference entries and web.config entries. awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with your target type. You might try the following:

1. Remove all service registrations and
   try them one at a time to determine
   the type that is causing the
   problem.
2. Ensure that you can successfully
   instantiate the target type
   yourself.
3. Verify that the target type doesn't
   have any other dependencies that are
   not accounted for in your service
   registrations.

It would be helpful to see the declaration and constructor(s) of the target type(s).

Try switching to another IoC Container:

Add a reference to MvcTurbine.Ninject.dll

Then:

```
public class MvcApplication : TurbineApplication
{
    static MvcApplication()
    {
        //ServiceLocatorManager.SetLocatorProvider(() => new UnityServiceLocator());           
        ServiceLocatorManager.SetLocatorProvider(() => new NinjectServiceLocator()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I disabled all the Registrations and made all my controllers not accept a single parameter. Is there something else I can do?

Comment: Browse to the DLLs for MvcTurbine and Unity in Windows Explorer. Right click each one and click the Unblock button if it is present. I had a similar problem with a reference to a DLL I had downloaded being blocked by the "This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer." and couldn't be loaded at runtime.

Comment: What version of MVC are you running?

Comment: See comments from OP. I am running latest beta V2. But that doesn't seem to impose the problem. It's only as soon as I add Db4objects.Db4o.Linq.dll this error message shows up. With turbine but without the Db4objects.Db4o.Linq.dll everything works, without turbine and with the library everything works too. Combine them and you get the message.

Comment: I wonder if this is actually a problem with Unity. Have you tried switching to Castle Windsor or Ninject? Nice thing about Turbine is you can switch IoC/DI containers with a reference and one line of code. See my answer for an updated code sample.

Comment: I tried with Windsor last night, but didn't check Ninject. Although I fear the problem might lie in the dbo4o lib rather then the Ioc containers. I'll update OP once I got the chance to check this out. As a side note: do you have any good resources on why to pick one over the other?

Comment: If both Windsor and Unity failed to load the type then I would definitely suspect a problem with the db40 lib. As for why to pick one IoC over another: I'm not sure. I'm pretty new to IoC/DI (been using it for about 2 weeks now :) ) My first shot at adapting my MVC 2 app to use Turbine went much like yours is so I switched to just using Ninject directly. Why did I pick Ninject over the others? It claims to be the "Ninja of dependency injection" which just sounds cool! :)

Comment: Hehe.. ninja's :)
Well, I tried swapping them (ref OP), nothing. And I really want linq2db4O. Hope I can somehow get the DB4O ppl check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff, MVC Turbine currently only supports MVC 1.0, I'm in the process of getting MVC 2.0 support for both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0. Please check http://turbineproject.com for information when they will be released.

Comment: My project is an MVC2 project and although it is currently only the "turbine'd" empty project template, it seems to run without any problems.. What are the current issues with Turbine + MVC2?

Comment: Mea culpa - I should have said that there is no "official" release yet for MVC 2.0, which means I've ran the unit tests, samples and compiled the against the MVC v2 binaries.  If it works out the box, that's good to hear! :)

If you run into any issues, don't hesitate to contact me.